# Spontaneous up spring boot context in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have an issue with spring-boot-test during deep dive in spring TestContext configuration.

Example project: [github example project](https://github.com/lavcraft/spring-boot-test-mistakes)

I have three Spring configurations with some beans (`Config1` - heavyweight config, and I need to cache it)

I use `@ContextHierarchy` for separate configs in the context, and I expect that Config1 will be loaded only once. (Used @ContextHierarchy because I did not find an analogue in spring-boot-test)

Full code:

```
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config1.class}),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config2.class}),
})
```

If I run the test, the Config1 was really cached! However, I see the following:

```
Started ConfigTest1
```

Two times
And

```
Started ConfigTest2
```

Only once. In my opinion, it is possible because `ConfigTest1` already cached as TestContext (it happens, because `ConfigTest1` and `ConfigTest2` contained in the same package)

That means spring boot up my spring context three times! Why?
See spring boot logo three times in log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)
```

What do you mean about this behaviour? Is it a bug or a feature? Maybe I do something wrong?

*Update1:*

Thanks a lot. However, if i set properties (or classes) in @SpringBootTest in different order in two test classes – no configuration will be cached :(

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config1.class}),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config2.class}),
})
public class ConfigTest1 {
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "property1=1")
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config1.class}),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config3.class}),
})
public class ConfigTest2 {
```

In case there is no properties – config1 really will be cached! And in this case – nothing cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working as it should!

You're just confused because of the fact that Spring Boot logs the name of the test class for which the `ApplicationContext` was loaded. Thus, you see `ConfigTest1` twice in the log, because two contexts are loaded for that test class.

If you add `logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.cache=debug` to `application.properties`, you'll see the following log output.

```
DEBUG ... c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@7a765367 testClass = ConfigTest1, locations = '{}', classes = '{class spring.test.mistake.delete.Config1}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@643b1d11, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6d00a15d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@475530b9], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
DEBUG ... c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@52feb982 testClass = ConfigTest1, locations = '{}', classes = '{class spring.test.mistake.delete.Config2}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@643b1d11, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6d00a15d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@475530b9], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7a765367 testClass = ConfigTest1, locations = '{}', classes = '{class spring.test.mistake.delete.Config1}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@643b1d11, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6d00a15d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@475530b9], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]]
DEBUG ... c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@5ddcc487 testClass = ConfigTest2, locations = '{}', classes = '{class spring.test.mistake.delete.Config3}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@643b1d11, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6d00a15d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@475530b9], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@44c73c26 testClass = ConfigTest2, locations = '{}', classes = '{class spring.test.mistake.delete.Config1}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@643b1d11, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6d00a15d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@475530b9], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]]
DEBUG ... org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@478db956 size = 3, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 1, hitCount = 11, missCount = 3]
```

Thus, there are in fact only three contexts loaded, namely the three you expect.